# convert string to memory stream - Memory stream is not expandable?

Tags: c#, memorystream

i was trying to write a string to a memory stream,
but failed with the error message:

```
Memory stream is not expandable.
```

the line of code that produces this problem:

```
context.Response.Filter = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPage));
```

anyone have a workaround/fix for that?

stacktrace:

```
[NotSupportedException: Memory stream is not expandable.]
   System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value) +9385744
   System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value) +50
   System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +265
   System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +9155697
   System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +159
   System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +52
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: what is `mypage' a string directly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? From what I got in the documentation, `HttpResponse.Filter` is not meant to be used like that.

Comment: @msarchet = yes, it is a string.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - if you try to manipulate the response, that is the way to go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx

Comment: Yes, but if you want to output stuff to the response, why not just call `Write`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: its inside an httpmodule... i dont want to write to the response, again, i manipulate the response.

Comment: Well, if it's inside a HttpModule, you have full control over the actual HTTP output. So it should be easy to write what you want.

Comment: You should probably be using a custom Stream that takes the current filter as an parameter  and appends to it.

Comment: @tvanfosson, i think you are right, got any example for that?

Comment: Please accept the most useful answer below

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The following code works correctly for me

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myPage = "test string";
        var repo =  new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPage));
    }
}
```

It seems that the correct way to do this is to create the `MemoryStream` using the default constructor

```
var repo = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
```

and then write to it

```
var stringBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPage);
repo.Write(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length);
```

if you want to be able to read the stream as normal (eg using a StreamReader) then you will also need to call:

```
repo.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 5):

A custom stream that appends the data would be more appropriate.

Minimally tested.  Assumes that you want the text written when the stream is flushed, and then only once.

```
public class AppendTextFilter : Stream
{
    private Stream Filter { get; set; }
    private string Text { get; set; }
    private bool TextWritten { get; set; }

    public AppendTextFilter( Stream filter, string text )
    {
        this.Filter = filter;
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return Filter.CanRead; } }

    public override bool CanSeek { get { return Filter.CanSeek; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return Filter.CanWrite; } }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        if (!TextWritten)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes( Text );
            Filter.Write( bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
            TextWritten = true;
        }
        Filter.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length { get { return Filter.Length + Text.Length; } }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return Filter.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            Filter.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
    {
        return Filter.Read( buffer, offset, count );
    }

    public override long Seek( long offset, SeekOrigin origin )
    {
        return Filter.Seek( offset, origin );
    }

    public override void SetLength( long value )
    {
        Filter.SetLength( value );
    }

    public override void Write( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
    {
        Filter.Write( buffer, offset, count );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `MemoryStream` from a byte array, you essentially create a wrapper around said array. Which means the stream's buffer cannot expand once it reaches its capacity.

However, an `HttpResponse.Filter` is essentially that: a *filter*. The documentation states:

> When you create a Stream object and set the Filter property to the Stream object, all HTTP output sent by Write passes through the filter.

So data ends up being written to the `MemoryStream`. So it would help to know what you're trying to achieve with this, exactly, because a `MemoryStream` would not make a useful filter...

Comment: i am trying to manipulate the response, added some text to the page. thats it.

Answer (score 2):

```
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("test.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer ))
                {
                    doc.Load(ms);
                }
                // Make changes to your memory stream here
                doc.Save(output);//Output stream has the changes.
            }
```